# Javascript onclick function call issue: won't pass a string

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

So the basic rundown is that I'm trying to create a rudimentary means of flagging inappropriate content on our web mapping application. 
Within a function that dynamically creates content for the sidebar of the webmap when the user clicks on a point I have this piece of code that should generate an image of a flag.

When the user clicks the flag, I want to run the function flagContent which should pass a url string into the function. From within this function I would then be able to
write it to a database later on (though I haven't made it this far yet).

Here are some code snippets I have been working with.:

1.This is where the flag image is generated

```
content += "<p class='info'><img id='flag' onclick='flagContent(" + attachmentInfo.url + ")
'src='assets/flag.png' style='height:15px'>Flag as inappropriate...</p>";
```

1. This is the connected function

   function flagContent(imageUrl){ console.log(imageUrl)}

So basically the url is a string and I'd like to be able to manipulate it within the flagContent function. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. When I pass a numerical parameter such as *attachmentInfo.objectID* I do not run into the same problem.

For what it's worth I also get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if there is additional information that could help to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: What does `attachmentInfo.url` evaluate to?

Comment: Is `height:15px` causing the issue? And `flagContent('" + attachmentInfo.url + "')`

Comment: Verify the HTML being generated. The string parameter of flagContent() must be quoted in Javascript, too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming that `attachmentInfo.url` would return a URL, which should be a string and it just needs to be surrounded by quotes.  Since you've already used both types of quotes, you will have to escape some quotes.

```
content += "<p class='info'>";
content += "<img id='flag' onclick=\"flagContent('" + attachmentInfo.url + "')\" src='file.png'/>";
content += "Flag as inappropriate...";
content += "</p>";
```

Doing this makes the final out put look like this:

```
<p class='info'>
  <img id="flag" onclick="flagContent('http://example.com')" src='file.png'/>
  Flag as inappropriate...
</p>
```

The problem you had was that the URL was not surrounded by quotes, and it saw `flagContent(http://example.com)` and didn't know what to do with those bare words not in a string.